# django-reversion how to get user-id

Tags: python, django, reversion, django-reversion

I'm using django-reversion for providing history for models 
I discovered that reversion creates two tables, the table 'reversion_revision' and the 'reversion_version' 
And in the reversion_revision, are stored the user id who makes last changes. 
But i cant get that information. I use the function 'reversion.get_for_object(Model)' to get all versions of certain model but the function only return's me the information who is stored in table 'reversion_version' and i need to get the user id of the table reversion_revision
Someone now how do i do to get User id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`revision` is a foreign key on `Version`. And, `reversion.get_for_object(Model)` simply returns a queryset of `Version`s. So, for any item in that query set, you can simply access the user as so:

```
version.revision.user
```

**UPDATE:** Just to be more explicit:

```
versions = reversion.get_for_object(MyModel)

for version in versions:
    print '%s made this revision' % version.revision.user.username
```

Comment: ok, I was experimenting with version
"version.reversion.get_for_object(model)"
but it gives me an error, can not import the version